# Heroku Node Crash: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am receiving the following Heroku logs when trying to deploy my node app. I cannot figure out the cause of this. I'm guessing this has to do with the favicon link in my `index.html` file?

**Heroku Log**

```
2020-03-25T14:07:37.323633+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-03-25T14:07:37.323633+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T14:07:40.667543+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.68.202/
2020-03-25T14:07:40.668023+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-03-25T14:07:40.668162+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-03-25T14:07:40.668280+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-03-25T14:07:40.668531+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-03-25T14:07:40.668533+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T14:07:40.815780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-25T14:07:40.794329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-25T16:50:20.606050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-25T16:50:29.481448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-03-25T16:50:32.126241+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.16.1
2020-03-25T16:50:32.126628+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
2020-03-25T16:50:32.126812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
2020-03-25T16:50:32.127129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.
2020-03-25T16:50:32.127378+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
2020-03-25T16:50:32.263784+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T16:50:32.263791+00:00 app[web.1]: > project-x@0.1.0 start /app
2020-03-25T16:50:32.263792+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-03-25T16:50:32.263792+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T16:50:34.783181+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.253.226/
2020-03-25T16:50:34.783787+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-03-25T16:50:34.783888+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-03-25T16:50:34.783977+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-03-25T16:50:34.784185+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-03-25T16:50:34.784187+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T16:50:34.903396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-25T16:50:34.886104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-25T20:32:58.790170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-stream-53835.herokuapp.com request_id=d958c692-68ad-4723-a7da-1b0fb261e74b fwd="73.60.116.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-25T20:32:59.217144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hidden-stream-53835.herokuapp.com request_id=1e9dbfb7-070b-485e-906b-a30a2e0dcc35 fwd="73.60.116.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**index.html**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
```

Comment: "App crashed" doesn't tell us anything useful. Is there anything else in your logs? If not, add some logging.

Comment: I am not sure what info from the log is useful or not for resolving this. I am seeing another warning (which I provided) in regards to the Node version I am using. I was using 12.16.1 but downgraded to 10.0.0 because of this. Not sure if this would cause the crash. Thank you

Comment: "Project is running at http://0.0.0.202/"... "Project is running at http://0.0.0.226/"—these are almost certainly wrong. Where are they coming from?

Comment: I corrected this, it should be 172.16.68.202. Thank you

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It should be whatever IP address and port Heroku gives you. _Again_, where is this IP address _coming from_?

Comment: I placed the 0's there. I was not sure if I should post this publicly admittedly. I see that its ok to now. The correct addresses are http://172.16.68.202/ and http://172.18.253.226/

Comment: Those are private IP addresses. For the third time, _where did you get them from?_ You should be binding to all available IP addresses, whatever they may be, probably by binding to `0.0.0.0` in your code, and the single port that Heroku gives you via the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: Those are the IP addresses that are generating in the log when I try to deploy the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever IP addresses you are assigned one time are going to change frequently. Don't bind to them specifically.

Instead, bind to *all available* IP addresses, which is typically represented by `0.0.0.0` or by not providing an IP address at all. Make sure to also use the port that Heroku specifies via the `PORT` environment variable.

Assuming you're using Express, [something like this should work](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/master/index.js):

```js
const express = require('express')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000  # Fall back to port 5000 if process.env.PORT is not set

express()
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```